# NGINX SSI serving from wrong upstream source

Tags: nginx

I have the following (highly simplified) NGINX configuration.  My goal is to serve small content fragments from 'secondhost' as part of the pages served from 'firsthost'.

```
upstream PrimaryHost {
    server firsthost.com:443;
}

upstream SSIHost {
    server secondhost.com:443;
}

server {
    listen                       443 ssl default_server;
    port_in_redirect             off;

    location ^~                  /ssi/ {
        proxy_pass               https://SSIHost;
    }

    location ~                   ^/ {
        ssi on;
        proxy_pass               https://PrimaryHost;
    }
}
```

There exists a file on secondhost: //secondhost/ssi/fragment.html
and within every HTML file on firsthost, the following SSI tag:

```
<!--# include file="/ssi/fragment.html" -->
```

A sample request to the above configuration would be:
https://example.com/home.html

The majority of the time, the home.html file from firsthost is served with the SSI fragment content embedded as expected.  However, occasionally a request to https://example.com/home.html serves only the content of //secondhost/ssi/fragment.html.

Can someone explain why this happens, why its intermittent, and how to fix it?

Thank you!